# Transparent URP material doesn't cast shadow

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I recently upgraded a project from SRP to URP but now transparent objects no longer cast shadows (even when alpha is 1). I want transparent materials to behave similar to SRP's 'transparent' or 'fade' materials. Also this issue occurs in Unity 2021 LTS and 2022 (Apple Silicon)

Opaque material:
[image: opaque]

Transparent Material:
[image: transparent]

Also here's the material's properties seen in the inspector:
[image: material properties]

Comment: I also posted this issue on Unity's forum so there might be an answer there if someone else ran into this issue: https://forum.unity.com/threads/transparent-material-not-casting-shadows.1295364/